# (Sharepoint 2007) Accessing Sharepoint Document Library and display its records in GridView

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We have created one Document Library.
User will upload his data to it.
I want to display All the documents uploaded by user on one page.
(Suppose I am login to the system then on pageload I need to fetch all the records from document library which are uploaded by me)
Document library may have more than one folders inside it,
means structure like following

Root1
    ->Folder1
          ->Folder2
Root2
   ->Folder1

So I need to search in every folder of this document library and show result in gridview.
Please help and provide if you have any reference to this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using CAML query, to build your query you can use a very nice tool called [U2U CAML Builder](http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) to generate the query like you want.
In C# part you create `SPQuery` and assign the generated CAML query from the tool as string and assign it to it

```
var query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' /><Value Type='UserMulti'>"+i +"</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

To Search in all folders just update the ViewAttributes property like the following

```
SPQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";
```

and call it like

```
var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(query);
```

where `list` is your `SPList` object

Comment: You are welcome, if it helped, you can mark it as an answer by click on the true sign below the rating arrows. Regards.

Comment: Hi,I am trying to fetch records from doc library which are uploaded by current user and want to show that result in gridview. I am using following different CAML Queries but getting some error.Please tell me where I am going wrong                        1)query.Query="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Created_x0020_By' LookupId='TRUE'/><ValueType='User'>"+205552+"</Value></Eq></Where>";2)query.Query="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value type='Integer'>"+205552+"</Value></Eq></Where>";                    My Doc Library field name is "Created By" and it's Type is "Person Or Group".